# how to format date using javascript

Tags: javascript, date

> user input in textbox

```
 22/05/0017
```

> i want to change it to but 1st have to check if there 00 after 2nd '/'

`22/05/2017`

> if current year is

```
 2017
```

> and it will change it to

`22/05/1917`

> if current year is

```
 1917
```

using Javascript.

Comment: It is unlikely that the current year is ever 1917 again. And it's also unlikely that a user enters 0017 when he means 2017. what kind of Spec is this?

Comment: basically i want to say check for current year.

Comment: if input is string input.replace('00',new Date().getFullYear().toString().substring(0,2))

Comment: but how to check if there 00 after 2nd '/'

Comment: check my answer. I hope it will work as per your expectation

Comment: but u have not check for 00 after 2nd '/' what if user already enter 2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this :**

```js
var dateStr = "22/05/0017";

var splitDate = dateStr.split("/");

var today = new Date();
var year = today.getFullYear();

var finalDate = splitDate[0]+ "/" +splitDate[1]+ "/" +year;

console.log(finalDate);
```

Updated answer as per the change request

```js
var dateStr = "22/05/0017";

var splitDate = dateStr.split("/");

if(splitDate[2].substring(0,2) == '00') {
  var today = new Date();
  var year = today.getFullYear();
} else {
  var year = splitDate[2];
}

var finalDate = splitDate[0]+ "/" +splitDate[1]+ "/" +year;

console.log(finalDate);
```

Comment: No need to check as you want to replace that from current year. You can directly replace it from current year without worrying about the value after the second /

Comment: check is needed

Comment: Why check is needed ? You want to replace value directly with current year as you mention in the OP. What will happen if user input 0007 ? follow the good approach instead of making things complex